# Angular JS filtering

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to sum the total score based on filters provided by text box variables.  I am attaching my javascript at the end.  Does anyone have any suggestions to sum multiple fields in Angular?

I am integrating this simple example into a larger set of columns to sum (like 10 of them).  I was thinking of using a JSON object to represent the sums of each column, but am unsure how to integrate everything with more than one column of data.

```js
// app.js
var app = angular.module('sortApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.sortType     = 'fish'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
  $scope.searchFish   = '';     // set the default search/filter term
  $scope.searchName = '';
  
  // create the list of sushi rolls 
  $scope.sushi = [
    { name: 'Cali Roll', fish: 'Crab', tastiness: 2, score: 3 },
    { name: 'Philly', fish: 'Tuna', tastiness: 4, score: 2 },
    { name: 'Tiger', fish: 'Eel', tastiness: 7, score: 5 },
    { name: 'Rainbow', fish: 'Variety', tastiness: 6: score, 1 }
  ];
  
  $scope.totalRecords = function(searchFish, searchName) {
   return $scope.sushi.reduce( function( current, record) {
  if( filterSushi( record, searchFish, searchName ) )
  {
   return current + record.tastiness;
  }
  else
  {
   return current;
  }
   }, 0 );
  };
  
});

function filterSushi( record,searchFish, searchName )
{
 var lowName = null;
 var lowFish = null;
 if( searchName.length > 0 )
 {
  lowName = searchName.toLowerCase();
 }
 if( searchFish.length > 0 )
 {
  lowFish = searchFish.toLowerCase();
 }
    var termInName = true;
    var termInFish = true;
     
 if( lowName != null )
 {
  termInName = record.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowName) > -1;
 }
 if( lowFish != null )
 {
  termInFish = record.fish.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowFish) > -1;
 }
 return !( !termInFish || !termInName );
}

app.filter('myTableFilter', function(){
  // Just add arguments to your HTML separated by :
  // And add them as parameters here, for example:
  // return function(dataArray, searchTerm, argumentTwo, argumentThree) {
  return function(dataArray, fish, name) {
      // If no array is given, exit.
      if (!dataArray) {
          return;
      }
      // If no search term exists, return the array unfiltered.
      //else if (!searchTerm) {
      //    return dataArray;
      //}
      // Otherwise, continue.
      else {
           var lowName = null;
     var lowFish = null;
   if( name.length > 0 )
   {
    lowName = name.toLowerCase();
   }
   if( fish.length > 0 )
   {
    lowFish = fish.toLowerCase();
   }
           // Return the array and filter it by looking for any occurrences of the search term in each items id or name. 
           return dataArray.filter(function(item){
              var termInName = true;
              var termInFish = true;
     
     if( lowName != null )
     {
    termInName = item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowName) > -1;
     }
     if( lowFish != null )
     {
    termInFish = item.fish.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowFish) > -1;
     }
              //return termInFish || termInName || termInTastiness;
     return !( !termInFish || !termInName );
           });
      } 
  }    
});
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Sort and Filter</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        body { padding-top:50px; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <p>Sort Type: {{ sortType }}</p>
    <p>Sort Reverse: {{ sortReverse }}</p>
    <p>Search Query: {{ searchFish }}</p>
  </div>
  
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search da Fish" ng-model="searchFish">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search da Name" ng-model="searchName">

      </div>      
    </div>
  </form>
  
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    
    <thead>
 <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'name'">
            Sushi Roll 
            <span ng-show="sortType == 'name'" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'fish'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
          <span ng-show="sortType == 'fish'" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
          Fish Type 
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'tastiness'">
          <span ng-show="sortType == 'tastiness'" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
          Taste Level 
          </a>
        </td>
         <td>
          Score
        </td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi| orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | myTableFilter:searchFish:searchName">
        <td>{{ roll.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ roll.fish }}</td>
        <td>{{ roll.tastiness }}</td>
  <td>{{ roll.score}}</td>
      </tr>
 <tr><td></td><td></td><td>total: {{totalRecords(searchFish,searchName);}}</td><td>TotalScore: ??</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    
  </table>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of angular you have access to an alias of a filtered array in `ng-repeat` using `as myFilteredArray`.

You can then use this to do your sums

```
<tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi| filter1 | filter2 | filter3 as filteredFish">

Total: {{totalRecords()}}
```

in controller

```
 $scope.totalRecords = function() {
    if(!$scope.filteredFish){
        return 0;
    }
    return $scope.filteredFish.reduce( function( current, record) {
        return current + record.tastiness;
    }, 0 );
 };
```

Note that the version af angular shown in question doesn't support `as`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/0iz00FME9Kdk9nschvY6)**</kbd>